# Fix childs' position while div is transitioning

Tags: javascript, css

My setup is the following

```
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class=element />
</div>
```

Markup

```
.wrapper {
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-color: red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.element {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.wrapper:hover {
    width: 800px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLzGXY

Right now, when I click on the `Icon`, the `Icon` moves into the middle of the `wrapper`, as it transitions. I want it to stay in the left, on its original position. How would I do that?

Comment: adding all your code would be useful: add the HTML. If we can recreated your code working in a fiddle its much easier to answer.

Comment: @Moose I edited my question.

Comment: ok see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve using set css property when mouse hover.

See, Below example.

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-color: red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.element {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.wrapper:hover {
    width: 800px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    justify-content: left;
    padding-left:35px;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class=element>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there are multiple ways to go about this -
If you are not averse to use positioning - you can set the `element` position as absolute and with some hacky `left` you can achieve what you want.

```
.element {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  left:37px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OoXOPo#anon-login

Or we can use `relative` with some a `justify-items:start` on the parent container to place the `element` in its place always

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLzeZp

Answer (score 0):

To keep the the square class element to the left, remove:

```
    .wrapper {
       justify-content:center;
    }
```

and then margin the element like so:

```
    .element {
        margin-left:35px;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/mGEqVL